# Does Core Graphics' transformation matrix work differently than iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, core-graphics

I've have [a class](https://github.com/MosheBerman/ScrollViewSnapshotter/blob/master/ScrollViewSnapshotter/ScrollViewSnapshotter.swift) that snapshots the contents of a scroll view by changing the `contentOffset` of the scroll view and translating the current transformation matrix, as it creates new pages in a PDF context. The result is a PDF that contains all of the contents of the scroll view, in PDF-page-sized chunks.

On iPad, this works in both orientations and both directions, but on iPhone, the snapshot fails (an empty PDF is generated) when the device is in landscape orientation. I was wondering if this has to do with the way iOS handles rotation on iPhone.

Is there something that I'm missing, or doing incorrectly?

Here's my code:

```
class ScrollViewSnapshotter: NSObject {

    func PDFWithScrollView(scrollview: UIScrollView) -> NSData {

        let pageDimensions = scrollview.bounds

        let pageSize = pageDimensions.size
        let totalSize = scrollview.contentSize

        let numberOfPagesThatFitHorizontally = Int(ceil(totalSize.width / pageSize.width))
        let numberOfPagesThatFitVertically = Int(ceil(totalSize.height / pageSize.height))

        let outputData = NSMutableData()

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(outputData, pageDimensions, nil)

        let savedContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
        let savedContentInset = scrollview.contentInset

        scrollview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero

        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        {
            for indexHorizontal in 0 ..< numberOfPagesThatFitHorizontally
            {
                for indexVertical in 0 ..< numberOfPagesThatFitVertically
                {

                    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

                    let offsetHorizontal = CGFloat(indexHorizontal) * pageSize.width
                    let offsetVertical = CGFloat(indexVertical) * pageSize.height

                    scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offsetHorizontal, offsetVertical)
                    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -offsetHorizontal, -offsetVertical) // NOTE: Negative offsets

                    scrollview.layer.renderInContext(context)
                }
            }
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

        scrollview.contentInset = savedContentInset
        scrollview.contentOffset = savedContentOffset

        return outputData
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if iPad doesn't do the same transforms on the current transformation matrix that the iPhone does. Is this true?

Comment: What is the OS version of the devices you are testing on?

Comment: This was iPad Air 2 and iOS 9.x and 10.x

Comment: maybe define "snapshot fails"

Comment: @paiv, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CGAffineTransform`. The affine transform functions operate on and return a `CGAffineTransform` data structure. The affine transform functions for Quartz operate on matrices, not on `CTMs`. You should use these ones to construct a matrix itself you then apply it to the `CTM` by calling a concatenation function `CGContextConcatCTM`.

Look at [Interface Orientation](http://blog.inferis.org/blog/2015/04/27/ios8-and-interfaceorientation/) article. There are some useful tips on transformation matrix.

Or you can use an extension:

```
extension CGAffineTransform {

    public func translatedBy(x tx: CGFloat, y ty: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform
    public func rotate(by angle: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform
    public func scaledBy(x sx: CGFloat, y sy: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll manually before taking a PDF, you'll see incorrect output on iPad as well.

You have to account for scrollView.bounds.offset:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(
    context,
    -offsetHorizontal + pageDimensions.minX,
    -offsetVertical - pageDimensions.minY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it for you... just add one line inside your loop:

```
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    {
        for indexHorizontal in 0 ..< numberOfPagesThatFitHorizontally
        {
            for indexVertical in 0 ..< numberOfPagesThatFitVertically
            {

                UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

                let offsetHorizontal = CGFloat(indexHorizontal) * pageSize.width
                let offsetVertical = CGFloat(indexVertical) * pageSize.height

                scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offsetHorizontal, offsetVertical)
                CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -offsetHorizontal, -offsetVertical) // NOTE: Negative offsets

                // Translate again, with the original Content Offsets
                // Positive X, Negative Y
                CGContextTranslateCTM(context, savedContentOffset.x, -savedContentOffset.y)

                scrollview.layer.renderInContext(context)
            }
        }
    }
```